# Menu action connection does not find slot

Tags: c++, qt, qobject, qtcore, qt-signals

I am creating a QSystemTrayIcon traymenu. Its contextmenu has several actions which I need to identify.

```
public slots:
    void s_showNote();

void Traymenu::createMainContextMenu(){
  ...
  std::string noteTitle = m_noteList[i]->getTitle();

  QString menuEntryName = QString::fromStdString(noteTitle);
  QAction *openNote = m_mainContextMenu.addAction(menuEntryName);

  QObject::connect(openNote,SIGNAL(triggered() ),this,SLOT(s_showNote()) );
      QVariant noteID;
      noteID.setValue(m_noteList[i]->getID());
      openNote->setData(noteID);
```

The error is

```
QObject::connect: No such slot QSystemTrayIcon::s_showNote()
```

All of the code above is a part of my class definition that inherits from `QSystemTrayIcon`. How can I call the SLOT?

Comment: You probably forgot the Q_OBJECT macro in your class declaration?

Comment: It was not there, if I put it in my header file, I get the error in `Traymenu::Traymenu(QApplication * appIn){` that says `undefined reference to 'vtable for Traymenu'`. Don't know how to get further...

Comment: Ah I needed to rerun qmake manually so it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have at least two issues ongoing:

- Use Q_OBJECT for QObject derived classes.
- You will need to re-run qmake correspondingly.

As for the first point, please use C++11 and at least Qt 5.2 in the future because in cases like this, you will get a static compiler time error which comes handy for avoiding these tedious issues.